# Get full source of multiple macro definitions using clang libtooling

Tags: clang, libtooling

Ultimately I'm trying to pull out relevant structures from thousands of existing c and c++ header files. I've been able to use libtooling to pull out a structure and all of the structures/enums/typedefs etc it relies on from various different headers.  Unfortunately when I get the source backing the Decls it still references the macros defined there in.  I'm currently trying to find a way to access and print the source of these macros but not having much luck when multiple macros are defined.

For example:

```
#define INT int
#define UNSIGNED unsigned
#define NAME name

typedef struct {
   UNSIGNED long INT NAME;
} test;
```

When I get the FieldDecl corresponding to name and get the SourceRange I see the spelling location pointing to "#define UNSIGNED unsigned".  I'd like to know how to get to the other macro definition's source locations.  I know that when I change "UNSIGNED long INT NAME;" to "unsigned long INT NAME;" the spelling location will then point to "#define INT int".  It seems as if names are treated differently as changing to "unsigned long int NAME;" leaves me with no spelling location.

Is there a way to get multiple spelling locations given a SourceRange?  Do I need to narrow down the source range some other way?  I've tried lexing to the next token but the doesn't leave me with a new spelling location. I'm also going to have to account for macros in arrays such as "int bob[MAX_WIDTH][MAX_HEIGHT]" but I'm hoping once I figure out my issues here that will become clear.  Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.